Applescript works on one document but breaks on an almost identical document
Code Set 1:
-- Code Set 1

tell application "Pages"
    activate
    try
        set theDoc to the front document
        tell theDoc
            set theText to body text as text
            set updatedText to my replaceScriptureReferences(theText)
            set body text to updatedText
        end tell
    on error errMsg
        display dialog "Error: " & errMsg buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" giving up after 5
    end try
end tell

on replaceScriptureReferences(theText)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "("
    set textItems to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    
    set updatedText to ""
    
    repeat with thisItem in textItems
        if thisItem contains ")" then
            set parenContent to text 1 thru ((offset of ")" in thisItem) - 1) of thisItem
            if parenContent contains ":" then
                set scriptureReferences to {}
                set scripturePattern to "\\d*\\s*[A-Za-z]+\\s*\\d+:\\d+(-\\d+)?"
                set refMatches to paragraphs of (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of parenContent & " | grep -oE " & quoted form of scripturePattern) as list
                
                set replacedReferences to {}
                repeat with aLine in refMatches
                    set end of replacedReferences to "[[" & aLine & "]]"
                end repeat
                
                set updatedText to updatedText & (replacedReferences as text) & text ((offset of ")" in thisItem) + 1) thru -1 of thisItem
            else
                set updatedText to updatedText & "(" & thisItem
            end if
        else
            set updatedText to updatedText & thisItem
        end if
    end repeat
    
    return updatedText
end replaceScriptureReferences

Code Set 2:
-- Code Set 2

tell application "Pages"
    activate
    try
        -- Attempt to get the front document
        set doc to front document
    on error
        -- Display an error dialog if no Pages document is open
        display dialog "No Pages document is open." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
        return
    end try
    
    try
        -- Attempt to retrieve the body text of the document
        set textBody to the body text of doc
    on error
        -- Display an error dialog if unable to retrieve the body text
        display dialog "Failed to retrieve the body text from the document." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
        return
    end try
    
    try
        -- Move text within double brackets to the next line
        set modifiedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of textBody & " | sed -E 's/\\[\\[([^]]+)\\]\\]/\\n[[\\1]]/g'"
        
        -- Attempt to set the modified body text back to the document
        set body text of doc to modifiedText
    on error
        -- Display an error dialog if any issues occur during the text modification process
        display dialog "An error occurred while processing the text." buttons {"OK"} default button "OK"
        return
    end try
end tell


This is my program that automatically formats my scripture for my presentation software.  Scripture references are to be in double brackets [[]] to show up in my presentation software.
The only clue I have is in my debugging software when I do step by step it is showing CR at the end of the line when it is brought into the code.
The funny thing is the documents that work do not show the CR. I have looked at hidden characters to see if there is something different. I cannot see a difference.  I will leave a sermon outline that works and one that does not.  This week this sermon worked.
Also this is the error:

Error: Can’t make text 11 thru -1 of item 16 of {"Used at Canal heights 20241229b evening service

This is the one that worked:
Used at Canal Heights 20241229a morning service

Letters of John: The Christian Walk.

INTRODUCTION

The walk of a believer is not static but a daily journey.
Christians are to align our daily lives to Christ’s teaching and example. (1 John 2:6)
There is a clear path for us to take. (John 14:6)
This lesson will look at this path.

WALK IN THE LIGHT

There is no darkness in God. (1 John 1:5; John 8:12)
The path will be clear for those that follow Him. (Ps 119:105; Pro 3:5-6)
Christians are to walk in purity. (1 John 1:5-7,9; Phil 2:15)

WALK IN THE TRUTH

Christians are to walk according to the truth. (2 John 1:4; Pro 3:3-4)
Truth is rooted in God’s Word. (John 14:6; John 17:17)
There is a cost to straying from this path. (2 John 1:7-11)


WALK IN LOVE

Christians are to walk in love. (2 John 1:5-6)
Love is the fulfillment of God’s law. (Matt 22:37-40; Rom 13:8-10)
The example of Jesus’ love. (1 John 3:16; Eph 5:2)
This love will be a testimony to the world. (John 13:35)

WALK IN THE EXAMPLE OF FAITHFUL BELIEVERS

Christians are to emulate good examples. (3 John 1:12; Ps 1:1-2)
Paul’s example. (1 Cor 11:1; Phil 3:17)
Discern good examples. (1 John 4:1; Phil 1:9-10)


CONCLUSION

The Christian walk is a journey toward a heavenly destination, transforming us into the image of Christ. (Rom 8:29)
Daily we must choose the path that aligns with God’s will, serving as a witness to the world.
Let us commit to walk in the way of Christ.

The one that does not work is as follows:
Used at Canal heights 20241229b evening service

Revelation: Christ Wins, Evil Loses, Hope Lives.

INTRODUCTION

Revelation reveals Christ’s victory and the ultimate defeat of evil. (Rev 1:17-18)
It encourages Christians to persevere in the faith, knowing the final outcome. (Rev 3:11)
This letter provides hope and assurance to believers in every age. (Rev 1:3)
This lesson will look at this victory.

CHRIST IS VICTORIOUS

Christ is ruler over all. (Rev 1:17-18, Matt 28:18)
Christ’s triumph over evil is guaranteed. (Rev 19:11-16; 1 Cor 15:24-26)
Christ’s victory is our victory. (1 John 5:4-5; John 16:33)

ALL ENEMIES ARE DEFEATED

Satan and his forces will be overcome. (Rev 12:11)
Death, sin and suffering will be destroyed. (Rev 21:4; 1 Cor 15:54-57)
The final judgment will bring justice. (Rev 20:10-15; Matt 25:31-33,46)

LIVE WITH THIS HOPE

Christians are to live with anticipation of Christ’s return. (Rev 22:12)
Live holy lives anticipating the new creation. (Rev 21:1-4; 1 John 3:2-3)
Share the hope of Christ’s return with others. (Rev 22:17; 1 Pet 3:15)


CONCLUSION

Christians are to hold firm to the victory of Christ and live with hope and perseverance. (Rev 3:11)
Our lives should reflect the ultimate triumph of good over evil. (Rev 17:14)
As we wait for Christ’s return, we are called to live in faith, hope and love, sharing His message with the world. (Col 1:5-6)


A question: do parentheses ever appear anywhere except around scripture references? If they're only used for references, there might be an easier way of doing this.

I see the problem: when there is no character (space, return, etc) after the last parantheses, the offset command tries to to go beyond the end of the text and throws the error. Give me a minute and I'll write something that works.

You make a great point in that parenthesis are rarely used outside of scripture references.  Also I can't believe you found the differences in these two documents so quickly.  I guess it is because I was unfamiliar with the error code and what it represented. Note that the way my Proclaim software "sees" these references is on a new line with the brackets at the very beginning of the line. That is why they are on their own line after the point being made and each reference must be on its own line.  Appreciate the fast response.

Also my Proclaim (presentation) software is giving me on screen the actual verses from my chosen translation at the time of preaching if that helps any.

Also to answer you question about before or after.  I generally make my point and show the verses to support my initial point, so it would need to be after my point for the scripture reference to appear.

It's just practice. In Script Editor, if you select Show Log from the View menu, you'll get a list of executed commands that tells you where and when errors occur, and then (if necessary) you can add log statements to see what the variables look like right before the error. But in this case it wasn't necessary because everybody gets out-of-range errors with the offset command. Counting characters algorithmically is a PITA. Glad I could help, though…

There are a couple of issues in your script that make debugging more difficult.  The first is having Pages display the dialog (because it is being done in the Pages tell statement) - as you have noticed, without a timeout it hangs.  Moving the display dialog statement out of the Pages tell statement (or targeting it with my) will avoid that.  The second is that the error dialog is getting blown out because you are using a reference to an item in the text items, so the whole list is being included.  In the main repeat loop, dereferencing the item will give you a better idea of where the error is coming from, for example:
   set thisItem to thisItem as text

From there you would see that your error is when the scripture reference is at the end of a line and you try to go past the closing paren.  A quick fix would be to compare the offset with the length of the line, for example:
   set theOffset to (offset of ")" in thisItem)
   if theOffset is (length of thisItem) then -- check if at end of line
      set updatedText to updatedText & (replacedReferences as text) & text 1 thru -2 of thisItem
   else
      set updatedText to updatedText & (replacedReferences as text) & text (theOffset + 1) thru -1 of thisItem
   end if


That would have saved me a ton of time. Thank you so much!

The following code mimics what you did just using text item delimiters. I took the liberty of combining your two code blocks, but they can be separated again if you need:
tell application "Pages"
    activate
    try
        set theDoc to the front document
        tell theDoc
            set theText to body text as text
            set updatedText to my replaceScriptureReferences(theText)
            set body text to updatedText
        end tell
    on error errMsg
        display dialog "Error: " & errMsg buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" giving up after 5
    end try
end tell

on replaceScriptureReferences(theText)
    -- save current delimiters
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    
    set firstPassRevision to swapDelimiters(theText, "(", return & "[[")
    set secondPassRevision to swapDelimiters(firstPassRevision, ")", "]]")
    
    --restore original text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
    
    return secondPassRevision
end replaceScriptureReferences

on swapDelimiters(theText, oldDelim, newDelim)
    -- break current text at old delimiter, and reconnect with new delimiter    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelim
    set textItems to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to newDelim
    set revision to textItems as text
    
    return revision
end swapDelimiters

I'm curious, though… Did you intend to have the scripture reference at the start of the next line after the quote, or would you prefer it at the beginning (or end) of the line that contains the quote? The latter seems more sensible to me, and I can make that modification, but I'm not sure what your aim is. Let me know.
